# Sources of quant finance / finance puzzles

Tags: resource

I was wondering if there are recurring puzzles in the area of quant finance / finance published by the industry similar to [ponder this of IBM Research](https://research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/index.shtml)?

Answer (score 1):

One recurring monthly puzzle column would be [Jane Street Puzzles](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/).

Answer (score 1):

[*Quantitative Portfolio Management: The Art and Science of Statistical Arbitrage* by Michael Isichenko](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119821320) includes quite a few finance interview questions.